# Issue with ConnectyCube User Session Token Creation - "Unexpected Signature"

Tags: node.js, connectycube

I am encountering a perplexing issue while working with the ConnectyCube REST API for user management. My code successfully generates a signature for actions, such as creating an `app session token`, but when attempting to create a `user session token`, the server consistently returns an "unexpected signature" error.

Here's the method I use to generate the signature:

```
const getSignature = () => {
  const nonce = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000);
  const timestamp = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
  const stringForSignature = `application_id=${config.applicationId}&auth_key=${config.authKey}&nonce=${nonce}&timestamp=${timestamp}`;
  const signature = crypto.createHmac('sha1', config.authSecret).update(stringForSignature).digest('hex');
  return { signature: signature, timestamp: timestamp, nonce: nonce };
}
```

The signature generation appears to work correctly, as I can successfully create an app session token using it:

```
const getAppSessionToken = async () => {
  const signature = getSignature();
  const response = await axios.post(
    'https://api.connectycube.com/session', {
    'application_id': config.applicationId,
    'auth_key': config.authKey,
    'nonce': signature.nonce,
    'timestamp': signature.timestamp,
    'signature': signature.signature
  }, { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' } });
  return response.data.session.token;
}
```

However, when attempting to create a user session token, the server responds with an "unexpected signature" error:

```
const createSessionWithLogin = async (emailAddress, password) => {
  const signature = getSignature();
  return await axios.post(
    'https://api.connectycube.com/session',
    {
      'application_id': config.applicationId,
      'auth_key': config.authKey,
      'nonce': signature.nonce,
      'timestamp': signature.timestamp,
      'signature': signature.signature,
      'user': {
        'email': emailAddress,
        'password': password
      }
    },
    {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
      }
    }
  );
}
```

I would appreciate any insights into what might be causing this issue or suggestions for troubleshooting. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can get user token by this code

```js
const crypto = require('crypto');
const axios = require('axios');

// Config object with your application credentials
const config = {
  applicationId: 'your App ID',
  authKey: 'your authKey',
  authSecret: 'your authSecret',
  emailAddress: 'your login id',
  password: 'your password'
};

// Function to generate the signature
const getSignature = () => {
  const nonce = Math.floor(Math.random() * 1000000);
  const timestamp = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000);
  const stringForSignature = `application_id=${config.applicationId}&auth_key=${config.authKey}&nonce=${nonce}&timestamp=${timestamp}`;
  const signature = crypto.createHmac('sha1', config.authSecret).update(stringForSignature).digest('hex');
  return { signature: signature, timestamp: timestamp, nonce: nonce };
};

// Function to get the application session token
const getAppSessionToken = async () => {
  const signature = getSignature();
  const response = await axios.post(
    'https://api.connectycube.com/session', {
      'application_id': config.applicationId,
      'auth_key': config.authKey,
      'nonce': signature.nonce,
      'timestamp': signature.timestamp,
      'signature': signature.signature
    }, { headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' } }
  );
  return response.data.session.token;
};

// Function to create a session with user login
const createSessionWithLogin = async (login, password) => {
    const signature = getSignature();
    const userData = {
      'user[login]': login,
      'user[password]': password
    };
  
    const requestData = {
      'application_id': config.applicationId,
      'auth_key': config.authKey,
      'nonce': signature.nonce,
      'timestamp': signature.timestamp,
      'signature': signature.signature,
      ...userData
    };
  
    return await axios.post(
      'https://api.connectycube.com/session',
      requestData,
      {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
      }
    );
  };
  

// Example usage
getAppSessionToken()
  .then(token => console.log("Session Token:", token))
  .catch(error => console.error("Error fetching token:", error));

// Example usage of createSessionWithLogin
createSessionWithLogin(config.emailAddress, config.password)
  .then(response => console.log("Session with login:", response.data))
  .catch(error => console.error("Error creating session with login:", JSON.stringify(error)));
```

Result
[image]

Comment: Wow it is working! Seems i missed adding user prefixes before login and password values.

Comment: I learn too, this is my first experience for ConnectyCube REST API.

Comment: Can you try entering wrong password ? It still returns a session, i'am confused

Comment: I checked wrong user id and wrong password do not matter, only  `applicationId`, `authKey`, `authSecret` matter.

Comment: I checked documentation in [here](https://developers.connectycube.com/server/auth?id=user-sign-in), Both user[login] and user[password] required. So It should be support but wrong information works.

Comment: Unfortunately i'm going to unmark your answer to not mislead people here.